# cloudstack api url is generated but the xml is showing error

Tags: xml, api, url, request, signature

I'm using Flex Builder 4 for requesting cloudstack APIs and for getting response. when i execute the program the url is generated. But the webpage is showing error like

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   -<listzonesresponse cloud-stack-version="4.0.1.20130201075054"><errorcode>401</errorcode>
   <errortext>unable to verify user credentials and/or request signature
   </errortext></listzonesresponse>
```

can anyone tell what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the API call isn't signed properly.

For guidance see [Introduction to the CloudStack API](http://www.slideshare.net/sebastiengoasguen/intro-to-cloudstack-api), **skip to slide #9**.